# How do i change the order of websites that appear in firefox address bar?

Tags: firefox, history, address-bar

Recently my history got frozen and it won't get updated (the history menu last 15 visited websites) so i have cleared some history and now my address bar websites got screwed up showing unneeded websites instead of my websites that i usually visit.

So is there a way to get around this and manage to choose what website to appear in the list? I've searched and tried lot of things without finding anything helpful.

Tried to delete the list then visit the websites that i want but then another list appear from history which i am not interested in. Is there some settings to set to fix that? i have seen bucketweight settings but not sure which settings that i need to change and to what. Also updateidle setting is missing on my config page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have found the solution. For those who wants to fix this. It seems that Firefox for some reasons doesn't add the website i visit if i type it directly. I had to go to click on the suggested history website shown in the address bar for it to add it again in the list of recently visited.